# How to ignore elements/attributes in XML when mapping to objects using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm working with mapping XML strings into POJOs and viceversa using JAXB 2.0, and I want to be able to determine the elements in a XML that should be mapped into my annotated POJO classes.

Let's say I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer id="1">
    <firstName>Peter</firstName>
    <lastName>Parker</lastName>
    <socialSecurityNumber>112233445566</socialSecurityNumber>
</customer>
```

And I want to map it to a class that ommits the socialSecurityNumber element:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

If I try to unmarshall this I get the error:

> unexpected element (uri:"", local:"socialSecurityNumber"). Expected elements are <{}lastName>

Is it possible to ignore elements/attributes from a XML that aren't present in my POJO classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default JAXB shouldn't be complaining about the extra element.  However you can specify an instance of `ValidationEventHandler` on the unmarshall to get the behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: I have a ValidationEventHandler but how can I set it so JAXB doesn't crash when parsing this xml?

Comment: @UrielArvizu - JAXB will only error out for events that you return false for i the event handler.

Comment: so I should return true if the error is related to this issue? That way I can get the mapping done right?

Comment: I'm checking and the `ValidationEventHandler`'s *handleEvent* method returning true solves my problem, but if I want to handle other errors, do I have to add an if statement to check if the error thrown was due to unexpected element?

Comment: also you mention `by default` JAXB shouldn't complain, but me getting this error means I'm not using it's default configuration?

Comment: i think you are using the JAXB 1.x. JAXB 2.x is not strict with extra elements.